# Returning the percentage of a list

Tags: python

I should start by saying I've done very little code and almost no Python, and haven't really done much math in a while either, I had a question on a test last week that I couldn't solve. I'll post my code below, does anyone know how to solve it and where I went wrong solving it? Any pointers would be appreciated.

"Write a function called percentageUnderTenPounds which takes as the input a list of prices, and returns the percentage of prices which are under 10 pounds. Arguments: a list of floats (containing the prices), return (a single float value containing the percentages under £10)"

```
def percentageUnderTenPounds(prices):
    under10 = 0
    sum1 = 0

    for number in prices: 
        if number > 10:
            sum1 += 1
        
        under10 = (sum1 /len(prices)) * 100
    
    return under10
```

Comment: ***percentageUnderTenPounds*** but you do       ***if number > float(10):***???

Answer (score 1):

You actually calculated the percentage of the numbers (in the list) which are greater than 10 pounds. You achieved this by first counting the numbers which are greater than 10 pounds (in sum1) and then divided by total numbers which gives you percentage of numbers which are greater than 10 pounds.

Slightly changing your solutions gives us this:

```
def percentageUnderTenPounds(prices):
    under10 = 0

    for number in prices: 
        if number < 10:
            under10 += 1

    under10Percentage = (under10 / len(prices)) * 100

    return under10Percentage
```

Note that instead of counting count of numbers greater than 10, I have counted count of numbers which are less than 10 (in `under10`) and then divided by total count of numbers to get the percentage.

Let me know if you are still confused :)

Comment: Yeah, thank you, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for being so clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
if number < 10:
    sum1 += 1
        
under10 = (sum1 /len(prices)) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way of doing this is:

```
# construct a list of all prices less than 10 pounds 
under_ten = [price for price in prices if price < 10]
print(len(under_ten) / len(prices) * 100)
```

Where here we use "list comprehensions".

Your answer was incorrect because you wrote `number > 10` instead of `number < 10` but also note that you were assigning `under10` in each loop through the for loop, which isn't incorrect but you only need to assign it once at the end:

```
def percentageUnderTenPounds(prices):
    under10 = 0
    sum1 = 0

    for number in prices: 
        if number < 10:
            sum1 += 1
        
    under10 = (sum1 /len(prices)) * 100
    
    return under10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel daft with the < 10 thing.